# Change the order of Columns in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to create something like reusable Control.

I have added a Page called MyDataGrid.xaml to my Project(WPFApplication2)'s root directory. I have changed the root element from Page to DataGrid and added a column to it. you can see that changes in the xaml below:

```
<DataGrid x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyDataGrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="X" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in the MyDataGrid.xaml.cs I changed the base class to DataGrid. You can see that below:

```
public partial class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public MyDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now I have MainWindow.xaml provided by default. I added this reusable control to the MainWindow.xaml and added some Columns to it as you can see below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Self:MyDataGrid>
            <Self:MyDataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="School" />
            </Self:MyDataGrid.Columns>
        </Self:MyDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**My Problem:**

When i run the program the Columns are in order below:

Delete Name Age Class School

In above mentioned columns Delete Column is Provided by Default and other columns are declared in MainWindow.xmal

Now, I want to change the order of columns so that the default column shows at the end of the DataGrid as below :

Name Age Class School Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not how you create reusable controls. You should define a class that just inherits to the `DataGrid` and use `Styles` against your custom controls.

The way you structured your `Reusable control` will always insert the `First Column` as the **delete**.

In order to fix what you have what I did is defined my `Delete column` as a resource.

```
<DataGrid x:Class="WindowsApplication1.Blah"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" x:Key="DeleteColumn">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="X" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="School" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then on my `.cs` file I made it look like this

```
public partial class Blah : DataGrid
{
    public Blah()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var templateColumn = this.Resources["DeleteColumn"] as DataGridTemplateColumn;
        this.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
    }
}
```

Now that'll always add the `Delete column` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I have done it the other way after I took a look at your answer. But the idea is the same & I got that idea from your answer. Thank you very much.